# React fetching data null pointer exception

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning react with redux and I want to achieve something like this:

When I go to this url:

some_url/posts/1

I want to fetch from my server some data and then show it on page.

However it throws null pointer exception because it takes some time to get data.

I did something like this but it doesnt looks well, what is the proper way to prevent this null pointer exception and wait untill data will arrive?

Inside my component:

```
 componentWillMount() {
 this.props.fetchPost( 
 parseInt(this.props.match.params.postId));
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {post.title}
        </div>
    )};
```

My action creator:

```
export function fetchPost(postId){

const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${postId}`);

return {
    type: FETCH_POST,
    payload: request
};
}
```

And reducer, here I just filled state with empty template of object which server is providing. Without this I got NullPointerException.

```
import { FETCH_POST } from "../actions";

export default function(state = {id: 0, title: "", infos: [{id: 0, content: "", authorId: 0}]}, action){
switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_POST:
        return action.payload;
  }

return state;
}
```

What is the proper way to wait until data will arrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions in redux should always return a plain JS object which should have a mandatory `type` property.

When you are executing async code in the action creator, the returned object is no longer a plain JS object.

If you have to use `redux` then you would have to use a middleware like `redux-thunk`.

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

However, middlewares are advanced topic in react & redux.

If you just want to fetch some data from your api, you can do that in plain react. But for using redux flow, use a middleware.
You can also do it without a middleware, but that is not the recommended approach.

Answer (score 1):

Axios is using [Promise to handle http responses aynshcronously](https://github.com/axios/axios).

> Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js

So when you return your request object, it is currently not resolved.
I think you need to refactor a little bit your code with something looking like:

```
function fetchPost(postId) {
   return axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${postId}`);
}

// And your action creator
function updateContent(payload) {
   return {
      type: UPDATE_CONTENT,
      payload: payload,
   }
}
```

And call that in your component:

```
componentWillMount() {
 fetchPost(parseInt(this.props.match.params.postId)).then(this.props.updateContent);
}
```

By the way, there are plenty of ways to do this, I think you should read axios documentation and pick the one you prefer and the one matching your application requirements.